# Visual Studio WCF Configuration Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a strange problem where when I run my WCF from Visual Studio, it works fine. However, when I publish it with visual studio, I get this strange error:

[image: Error]

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, If you use CodeDom provider in your application,the project output path directory the codedom dll is available. So application will work in the normal run, publish time the dll not moved in the publish folder. so check publish folder itself having the dll.

Comment: bin>WcfService2.dll is present in the published folder